# Need to include .pdf files only while searching by partial file name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have multiple PDF files example TK4156-10093411.pdf and I need to be able to search by only a part of the name like 4156 and inlcude .pdf files only.

```
# Set the path to the folder you want to search
$folderPath = "C:\temp"


# Search the folder for the PDF file
$pdfFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter $fileName -Include '*.pdf' -Recurse

# Check if the PDF file was found
if ($pdfFile)
{
    # PDF file was found, so open it in Adobe Reader
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" -ArgumentList $pdfFile.FullName
}
else
{
    # PDF file was not found
    Write-Output "PDF file not found"
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your code?

Comment: The filter option does not work. If I search a file by name it doesn't find the file unless I include the file extension as well.

Comment: the easiest to do it is just remove `-Include '*.pdf'` and use `-Filter *4156*.pdf`

Comment: This is helpfull except 4156 is not the only number I want to search. I actually have user input in the script but wanted to keep the question simple.  So $fileName = Read-Host is what I have so I need to be able to do a partial match on the file name from the user input and only include PDF files.

Comment: So then use `-Filter "*$fileName*.pdf"` (mind the double quotes)

Comment: that worked, thank you very much. I can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: No, it is just a comment after all, because this was very basic. However, you can [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you like.